# not able to login in ubuntu box with root password

Tags: server

i have ubuntu 10.04 on my sytem, i run command apt-get install csh on the system and try to change the shell by command chsh -s but now the prob is when i try to login the system by ssh i am not able to login by any user account except one and try to change the user su - root it is showing cannot execute c: no such file or directory and look in the /etc/passwd file for root account in shell field C is written in place of /bin/sh help me out to restore the settings

Answer (score 2):

Boot live media.

Make sure your local HD is mounted by browsing for it in nautilus.

Open a terminal: `CTL + ALT + T`

Get root and change it to whatever shell you want:

```
sudo su
cd /media/partitionname/etc/
nano passwd
```

navigate to the root line which you say looks like this:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:C
```

make it look like this to restore default:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

Press `CTL+X` then `Y` then `Enter`
It should save.
Now type:

```
cd /
sync
exit
exit
```

Unmount the drive with the eject button in the nautilus window and reboot.

Easy peasy.

Now that it's correct you're able to log in as long as you don't run chsh -s c again.  If you want to change a user's shell you specify the full path to the shell as expressed in /etc/shells like `chsh -s /bin/csh` **NOT** this `chsh -s c`

Comment: thankx aking1012, can u tell me please why the passwd file changes when i run the command chsh -s c. i m new to ubuntu.        thanks again..

Comment: I think you made a typo.  chsh is change shell.  csh is a shell.

Comment: why i m not able to login by any user root etc..

Comment: >>there is only one user account by which i can login.when trying to switch user #su - root it ask for password when i write password it is showing cannot extcute c: no such file or directory.

Comment: hi aking1012..>> i was able to login to the system in resue mode and made the changes now my box is working fine..:):)